# Fault in magento order proces

Tags: magento, error-handling, module, invoice, createfile

I get an error when I try to make my invoice in the magento backend.
I select an order and click on the invoice, in the next screen I select email copy of invoice and then I select submit invoice.
After the click I get a white page. When I get back i see the invoice has been created?

In the log i see this error:

```
    2015-04-17T08:27:40+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ongeldig bloktype: Mage_Mostviewed_Block_List' in /home/admin/domains/doehetzelfalarm.nl/public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/admin/domains/doehetzelfalarm.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Ongeldig blokty...')
#1 /home/admin/domains/doehetzelfalarm.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('mostviewed/list', Array)
#2 /home/admin/domains/doehetzelfalarm.nl/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(169): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('mostviewed/list', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
```

I dont use the module mostviewed?
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even if you do not use this extension something in your code is trying to use this extension.

It appears to be in one of your transactional emails. If these are set-up via the admin then simply view the emails under `System->Transactional Emails` and find the call to `mostviewed/list`.

If you cannot find either the email or the code snippet then I would suggest that this is added via a layout handle or some call in a template so search in your code base for the snippet `mostviewed/list` and see what you can find.

Comment: I searched the email templates, but i can't find anything with the text mostviewed in it :(
I've searched in the files (app-locale-*language*/template/email) but in these file's i didn't find the text.
Hmmmmm i really hope to avoid an new installation

Comment: Then look into the code base itself for `mostviewed/list` most IDEs have a nice search function that should cover this or something like grep if you do not have an ide